# MITMPROXY - Changing Request Data of captured request and replaying it

Tags: mitmproxy

I have been scrolling web for around 3 days to look for a solution on how can I automatically edit the request data sent to https://example.com/login and then replay it using mitmproxy.

For example if I will send an POST request to example.com/data with request data: `{"auth":"failed"}`, mitmproxy will edit the request body to `{"auth":"ok"}` and then it will replay the request.

Any help is appreciated

I tried looking at mitmproxy documentation but couldn’t find any function that will work for my needs.

Comment: Are you sure you want to replay the request and not just modify? Replay means "send again" so at the server side there would be two requests from you with different content. Also your description is quite confusing because usually not the client sends data like `{“auth”:”ok”}` to the server but the other way round (response).